# What is the minimum number of observations required per group for One-Way Anova?

Tags: statistics, anova

Not really a code-related question per se, but more statistical. I plan to conduct a One Way Anova comparing mean catch rates (from fishing) across 3 locations, whereby there were only 4 surveys conducted at each location to calculate this mean catch rate (North: n=4, East: n=4, West: n=4).

With n=4, is it appropriate to conduct a One Way Anova, or is that number of observations too small?

Answer (score 0):

minimum total sample size should be n = k+1 = 4
You can read about it [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_minimum_sample_size_for_a_one-way_ANOVA)